# Set encoding of XML using Jaxb properties

Tags: encoding, properties, jaxb

I configured my web service client to use `Moxy` to `marshall / unmarshall` the service payloads. My service client does not have a control on the `Jaxb configuration`.
That said, I have configured my client to use `Moxy` by adding a `jaxb.properties` file with the entry as follows::

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

I have a requirement to change the encoding of the payload so that its::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
```

Is this possible by adding an entry to `jaxb.properties` (as it would be a lot of work for me to inject this value via code, due to the various frameworks we have in place).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Encoding for MOXy and all JAXB implementations is controlled by the `JAXB_ENCODING` property set on the `Marshaller`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-java-io-files-streams-readers.html

Comment: Thanks, Just wanted to confirm an alt / non-code solution (e.g. using jaxb.properties) was not available.

Comment: marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
this work for me Thanks.