# JAXB element possibly altering encoding of string

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, cxf

I've created a web service and generated java files using the CXF wsdl2java tool.
Now the parameters passed are stored as JAXBElements. When I send the values (in arabic) to my web service class they show as question marks. However when I print the value of the JAXBElement before it reaches my web service it's correct. Is the encoding changing between my test client and the web service? and if so how can I preserve the arabic characters?

Comment: Make a unit test for marshalling - do you get missing characters there?

Comment: This post contains the encoding proerties for JAXB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21018152/set-encoding-of-xml-using-jaxb-properties

Comment: @lexicore sorry I'm new to this, how would I do that?

Comment: How are you viewing the XML when it appears wrong.  Most often the XML is correct and it's just a limitation of the application being used to view the XML.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I'm not viewing the XML, I set up a breakpoint in my web service class to check the values there and I see it as question marks

Comment: Are you generally able to see those characters in the debugger?  If you are not sure you can populate a `String` character in some variable and introspect it.